# Converting binary choices to distance matrix

Tags: python, data-analysis, analysis

I am trying to wrangle a survey of binary choices to a distance-based matrix (or plot). Say I have done a survey where I made people choose between A, B, C and D in binary choices.

These are my survey questions with binary choices, answered by 100 people:

```
Q1: Choose A or B
Q2: Choose A or C
Q3: Choose A or D
Q4: Choose B or C
Q5: Choose B or D
Q6: Choose C or D
```

And my input data now looks like this:

```
            Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6
Person00    A   C   D   B   B   C
Person02    A   C   A   B   D   D
Person03    B   A   A   C   B   C
Person04    A   A   A   C   B   D
...
Person99    B   C   D   C   D   D
```

Now I want to transform this data into overall distances between the answers. In other words: between A, B, C, and D (not between the persons). People who would choose A for Q1 for instance, how much do they prefer B in other questions where A is not an option? Do they *never* choose D?

I've looked into cosine similarity and multidimensional scaling, but I'm having a hard time to know where to start conceptually. Maybe I should dummy-code every question? I'm trying to work towards a distance matrix, or even better some kind of plot:

[image: Example desired output]

Any help with what makes sense here would be very appreciated. Preferably in the form of Python-code, but also general ideas very welcome and appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing A, B, C and D are the same in every question, like candidates for office?  It feels like more than 2D.

Comment: Correct, these answers are the same in every question. It would be more than 2D, but wouldn't MDS be an option to still visualize distances (or 'clusters')?

Comment: You might assign 6 angles +/- to each bit and so position like responses as counts in a relation to each other, not graphing zero counts within the 64 possibilities, 0 to 63:count, with a key that says 0 is a<b a<c a<d b<c b<d c<d.  But a 60 degree and a 300 degree bit difference plots straight up like a zero degree one bit distance, but farther up.  A 0, 120, 240 would walk you back to the center, cancelling out.  It's a bit like color.

Comment: Maybe start with the most popular choices,t connect them by lines in an arbitrary angle and a length of the number of bits different.  For instance, if 0 is mot popular but there are votes for 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 15, then 1 2 and 4 would be 1 length away from 0, and then find choices that are the least bits away from any of those 4 and attach them to the nearest neighbors, then repeat, somewhat like a min spanning tree, growing from most popular on the left or, if a tie right and left, to nearest neighbors towards the middle. If 0 is neighbor to 1 2 4 9, 0 connects to 1 2 4 length 1 and 9 length 2.